# call image from database on index page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

i want to call images from database on index page but somethings going wrong.

when i try it on admin panel its okey but on index page, i can not do that.

thats mine index page codes.

```
<?php include ("includes/header.php");?>
<?php include_once ("includes/config.php");?>
<!--database start-->
<?php
   $test=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siteler");
   $sayi=mysql_num_rows($test);
   $deneme=mysql_fetch_row($test);
?>
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>
      <?php
         while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back-colour">';
            echo '<p><img src="'.$deneme['site_pic'].'"></p>';
            echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['site_name']. '</p>';
            echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['site_ref']. '</p>';
            echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['bet_turu']. '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
      }?>
   </div>
</div>
<!--database end-->
```

and how it looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYBeh.jpg

with the same codes my images looks like good on admin panel.

my folders design here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvLMq.jpg

Comment: Index and admin paths are the same?

Comment: nope. you can check the folders design here. http://imgur.com/khqiFew my index page is below. admin pages are under the admin folder.

Comment: what is the current img src?

Comment: So use an absolute path for the images rather than relative. (also note you have 2 index files so just saying view the image isn't useful)

Comment: first one is the admin index page. the other which is the site index page. i want to call images on site index page.

Comment: current images under the - htdocs\test\images

Comment: Use the absolute path and they will work everywhere. The relative path is relative to where you are, absolute will be the same everywhere.

Comment: can u give an example about abs path? edit: i got it. i'll try.

Comment: `img src="/this/is/full/web/path/to/image/'.$imagename` Open the developer console, view the `network` tab, and you should see why the image call fails currently.

Comment: <?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/image/test.jpg";
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check this code

```
<?php

while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
 $full_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $full_path .= "/images/".$deneme['site_pic']; // change it as your folder
 // echo $full_path is not working and chnage it
 echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back-colour">';
 echo '<p><img src="'. $full_path.'"></p>';
 echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['site_name']. '</p>';
 echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['site_ref']. '</p>';
 echo '<p class="box-design">' .$deneme['bet_turu']. '</p>';
 echo '</div>';
 }?>
```

if not work then just echo

```
echo $full_path;
```

in comment code then you can see path then easily change it and work any place from your site